# In the Dickensian era, was a capital letter preserved through apostrophe contractions?

Tags: history, capitalization, apostrophe

Assume that a certain word **is** capitalised, for example "Microsoft."

Say (for whatever reason, perhaps slang) you were going to shorten that certain word, using an apostrophe.

Today, I'd say we would write: 'soft

(So for example: "I've worked at 'soft for years...")

We would not keep the capitalisation through the contraction.  (So, I'd say, we would **not** write "I've worked at 'Soft for years...")

Question: what happened in 1850?

(Of course, the overall study of changes in capitalisation is a big topic; hopefully there's an expert here.)

---

Still very little information on this, other than one (great) example found by Stoney. Anyone??

Comment: I believe we still capitalize contractions at the beginning of sentences: *'Twas the night before Christmas, and ...*. So you're looking for a circa-1850 example of a contraction of a proper noun.

Comment: Australia sometimes gets abbreviated from the front and it's normally written as _Stralia_ or _'Stralia_.

Comment: Also *'Merica*.

Comment: Looking in Google Books in the 19th century, it usually seems to have been abbreviated *'Merica*. Here is an [example](http://books.google.com/books?id=HdsRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA356&dq=Dickens+%22Merica%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zHvbU_CyOI_LsASNzoKQAg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Dickens%20%22Merica%22&f=false).

Comment: [Here's a question relating to this issue from _A Tale of Two Cities_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188209/what-does-nation-stand-for-in-this-context)

Answer (score 3):

An instance of precisely this use is the common 18th- and 19th-century abbreviation by London financial traders of  *Exchange* (referring to the Stock Exchange or the Royal Exchange) to *’Change* , most often in the phrase *on ’Change*.

A quick troll through Google Books suggests that in the 18th century both the apostrophe and the capital were used or omitted freely with this short form; but in the 19th century both are standard, although not inevitable.

Comment: Your second paragraph: *"A quick troll through Google Books suggests that in the 18th century both the apostrophe and the capital were used or omitted freely"* are you talking about in "'Change"?

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes. That's the only one that came to mind.