# What does this "Change" mean in Charles Dickens’ ‘A Christmas Carol’?

Tags: meaning, literary-english, charles-dickens

The word *Change* doesn't seem to make much sense in this quote from *A Christmas Carol.* To emphasis the sentence, I kept it in bold-type.

> MARLEY was dead, to begin with. There
>   is no doubt whatever about that. The register
>   of his burial was signed by the clergyman,
>   the clerk, the undertaker, & the chief mourner.
>   Scrooge signed it. **And Scrooge's name was good
>   upon 'Change, for anything he chose to put his
>   hand to.**

Comment: Related [What does “ 'Nation ” stand for in this context?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188209/what-does-nation-stand-for-in-this-context?lq=1)

Comment: Mr. Quilp made "appointments on 'Change with men in glazed hats and round jackets ...." The Old Curiosity Shop, chapter IV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence relies on the word 'Change, which is a shortened form of Exchange - the stock exchange. The sentence means that Scrooge had a good reputation on the stock exchange and that his signature carried weight. There is a clue to working out the meaning, since Change begins with a capital letter, indicating that it is a proper noun and not a verb or abstract noun in this context.

Comment: The other clue, of course, being the apostrophe - indicating one or more missing letters in that proper noun.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Actually, there's more to it than that. Note this definition 3 for ***change*** in the full OED: *A place where merchants meet for the transaction of business, an exchange. (**Since 1800, erroneously treated as an abbreviation of Exchange, and written 'Change.**) Now chiefly in phr. on 'Change, at the Exchange.* So it's *not* a "Dickensism" anyway, and strictly speaking it's not an abbreviation either (or wasn't, until 1800 a few decades before Dickens perpetuated the "erroneous" usage complete with errant apostrophe).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting. Well, I vote for a *`Dickensism`* tag. We have one for Shakespeare.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: But as established by my earlier comment, Dickens used it at least 4-5 decades *after* the "erroneous" usage had already been recorded, so it's not really what most people would consider a "Dickensism" (which would tend to imply a usage either *coined* or *massively popularised* by the man). Which might perhaps apply in rare instances, but I don't think Dickens changed the actual language to anything like the extent Shakespeare did (or at least, *seems to have*, from the current perspective).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, the tag is `dickens`, there are a number of questions related to passages/terms taken from his books. I think he merits a tag all to himself. I had considered, momentarily, `19th-century-english` but then thought better of it. The `meaning` tag is too vast and general IMHO

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Possibly. But I'd have thought [*meaning-in-context*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) (where "context" = "Shakespeare", "Dickens", "Victorian English", "medical texts", "bog-snorkelling", what-have-you) should be sufficient "granularity" for usages which aren't "widespread and/or current" and don't easily fit into one of the larger/more general categories such as *archaic, dialectal*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a note by Michael Slater:

'Change: The Royal Exchange in the City of London, which functioned as a trading centre from 1570 to 1939.

Michael Slater. Notes, p. 275. In. Charles Dickens. A Christmas Carol and Other Christmas Writings. London: Penguin Books, 2003.

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that because Scrooge deals with a lot of stock exchange and holds a good reputation, his name is well known as very reliable when he puts it down on something, which suggests that Marley is indubitably dead. Later on in the story, when Marley's ghost visits Scrooge, this should make us believe that spirits are real, because of how certain Dickens has made Marley's death seem at the start of the novella.